# Cluster zooming Error: <image> attribute x: Expected length, "NaNNaNNaNNaN"

Tags: highcharts

When using cluster in a scatter series, and using symbols for each point marker, I am getting this error in chrome console, after I click the cluster and zooming happens

> Cluster zooming Error: <image> attribute x: Expected length, "NaNNaNNaNNaN".

Here is the stack trace

```
highcharts.js:68 Error: <image> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".
_defaultSetter  @   highcharts.js:68
(anonymous) @   highcharts.js:45
A   @   highcharts.js:14
attr    @   highcharts.js:45
animate @   highcharts.js:40
Scatter.animateClusterPoint @   marker-clusters.src.js:676
(anonymous) @   marker-clusters.src.js:1708
(anonymous) @   marker-clusters.src.js:1707
(anonymous) @   marker-clusters.src.js:1693
(anonymous) @   highcharts.js:29
c.fireEvent @   highcharts.js:29
redraw  @   highcharts.js:282
zoom
```

Comment: Also it appears that the first point shown after the zooming takes effect - is not positioned in the x,y coordinate it should be

Comment: Hi @orenise, That problem is a bug in Highcharts. I have reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13302

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround - You can disable the series cluster animation as follows:

```
    {
    type: 'scatter',
    cluster: {
      animation: false,
    },
    data: ...
};
```